# How to run process as different user from windows service

Tags: python, windows, service, process

I've created a service which is already started before a user logs in. The service is running as "Network Service" user. From time to time it has to run an update process which needs to be run as a domain user. The case that no user is logged in while the update process is started has to be considered. It is not possible to run the service as the domain user because of password rules (need to be changed from time to time).
The password for the domain user is fetched from another machine when the update process needs to be run.
My problem is that the service is able to create the process as the domain user with CreateProcessWithLogonW but as soon as the process is started it is immediately destroyed. Return value is 0 and I get no stdout and no stderr. The only hint I get is an entry in the event log with the error code 0xc0000142.
I've also tried several other solutions I've found on the web. But no solution works. For example I've also tried LogonUser -> Adjust privileges -> CreateProcessAsUser.
The OS is Windows 7.
The update program is just a console application. I only need return code, stdout and stderr. No window should popup when the process is started.
Can anyone help me with a working solution? Best would be an example in Python. Thanks in advance.
Best regards,
Martin

**Update:**
Currently I ended up with the following code:

```
import os
import sys
import types
import subprocess
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
import win32con
import win32event
import win32api
import win32security

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error = True)
advapi32 = ctypes.WinDLL('advapi32', use_last_error = True)

ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE = 0x0006
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = wintypes.HANDLE(-1).value
INVALID_DWORD_VALUE = wintypes.DWORD(-1).value

DEBUG_PROCESS                    = 0x00000001
DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS          = 0x00000002
CREATE_SUSPENDED                 = 0x00000004
DETACHED_PROCESS                 = 0x00000008
CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE               = 0x00000010
CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP         = 0x00000200
CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT       = 0x00000400
CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM          = 0x00000800
CREATE_SHARED_WOW_VDM            = 0x00001000
INHERIT_PARENT_AFFINITY          = 0x00010000
CREATE_PROTECTED_PROCESS         = 0x00040000
EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT     = 0x00080000
CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB        = 0x01000000
CREATE_PRESERVE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x02000000
CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE        = 0x04000000
CREATE_NO_WINDOW                 = 0x08000000

STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW    = 0x00000001
STARTF_USESIZE          = 0x00000002
STARTF_USEPOSITION      = 0x00000004
STARTF_USECOUNTCHARS    = 0x00000008
STARTF_USEFILLATTRIBUTE = 0x00000010
STARTF_RUNFULLSCREEN    = 0x00000020
STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK  = 0x00000040
STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK = 0x00000080
STARTF_USESTDHANDLES    = 0x00000100
STARTF_USEHOTKEY        = 0x00000200
STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME  = 0x00000800
STARTF_TITLEISAPPID     = 0x00001000
STARTF_PREVENTPINNING   = 0x00002000

SW_HIDE            = 0
SW_SHOWNORMAL      = 1
SW_SHOWMINIMIZED   = 2
SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED   = 3
SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE  = 4
SW_SHOW            = 5
SW_MINIMIZE        = 6
SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7
SW_SHOWNA          = 8
SW_RESTORE         = 9
SW_SHOWDEFAULT     = 10 # ~STARTUPINFO
SW_FORCEMINIMIZE   = 11

LOGON_WITH_PROFILE        = 0x00000001
LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY = 0x00000002

STD_INPUT_HANDLE  = wintypes.DWORD(-10).value
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = wintypes.DWORD(-11).value
STD_ERROR_HANDLE  = wintypes.DWORD(-12).value

SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000
WAIT_OBJECT_0 = win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0
WAIT_OBJECT_1 = WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1


class HANDLE(wintypes.HANDLE):
    __slots__ = ( 'closed', )

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value or 0

    def Detach(self):
        if not getattr(self, 'closed', False):
            self.closed = True
            value = int(self)
            self.value = None
            return value
        raise ValueError("already closed")

    def Close(self, CloseHandle=kernel32.CloseHandle):
        if self and not getattr(self, 'closed', False):
            CloseHandle(self.Detach())

    __del__ = Close

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%d)" % (self.__class__.__name__, int(self))


class PROCESS_INFORMATION(ctypes.Structure):
    """https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684873"""
    __slots__ = '_cached_hProcess', '_cached_hThread'

    _fields_ = (('_hProcess',   HANDLE),
                ('_hThread',    HANDLE),
                ('dwProcessId', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwThreadId',  wintypes.DWORD))

    @property
    def hProcess(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_cached_hProcess'):
            self._cached_hProcess = self._hProcess
        return self._cached_hProcess

    @property
    def hThread(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_cached_hThread'):
            self._cached_hThread = self._hThread
        return self._cached_hThread

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.hProcess.Close()
        finally:
            self.hThread.Close()

LPPROCESS_INFORMATION = ctypes.POINTER(PROCESS_INFORMATION)

LPBYTE = ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.BYTE)


class STARTUPINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    """https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331"""
    _fields_ = (('cb',              wintypes.DWORD),
                ('lpReserved',      wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ('lpDesktop',       wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ('lpTitle',         wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ('dwX',             wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwY',             wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwXSize',         wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwYSize',         wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwXCountChars',   wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwYCountChars',   wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwFillAttribute', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwFlags',         wintypes.DWORD),
                ('wShowWindow',     wintypes.WORD),
                ('cbReserved2',     wintypes.WORD),
                ('lpReserved2',     LPBYTE),
                ('hStdInput',       wintypes.HANDLE),
                ('hStdOutput',      wintypes.HANDLE),
                ('hStdError',       wintypes.HANDLE))

    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.cb = ctypes.sizeof(self)
        super(STARTUPINFO, self).__init__(**kwds)


class PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

PPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST = ctypes.POINTER(PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)


class STARTUPINFOEX(STARTUPINFO):
    _fields_ = (('lpAttributeList', PPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST),)

LPSTARTUPINFO = ctypes.POINTER(STARTUPINFO)
LPSTARTUPINFOEX = ctypes.POINTER(STARTUPINFOEX)


class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('nLength',              wintypes.DWORD),
                ('lpSecurityDescriptor', wintypes.LPVOID),
                ('bInheritHandle',       wintypes.BOOL))
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.nLength = ctypes.sizeof(self)
        super(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, self).__init__(**kwds)

LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = ctypes.POINTER(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)

class HANDLE_IHV(HANDLE):
    pass

class DWORD_IDV(wintypes.DWORD):
    pass

def _check_ihv(result, func, args):
    if result.value == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return result.value

def _check_idv(result, func, args):
    if result.value == INVALID_DWORD_VALUE:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return result.value

def _check_bool(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

def WIN(func, restype, *argtypes):
    func.restype = restype
    func.argtypes = argtypes
    if issubclass(restype, HANDLE_IHV):
        func.errcheck = _check_ihv
    elif issubclass(restype, DWORD_IDV):
        func.errcheck = _check_idv
    else:
        func.errcheck = _check_bool

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211
WIN(kernel32.CloseHandle, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.HANDLE,) # _In_ HANDLE hObject

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685086
WIN(kernel32.ResumeThread, DWORD_IDV,
    wintypes.HANDLE,) # _In_ hThread

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425
WIN(kernel32.CreateProcessW, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpApplicationName
    wintypes.LPWSTR,        # _Inout_opt_ lpCommandLine
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # _In_opt_    lpProcessAttributes
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # _In_opt_    lpThreadAttributes
    wintypes.BOOL,          # _In_        bInheritHandles
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwCreationFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpEnvironment
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpCurrentDirectory
    LPSTARTUPINFO,          # _In_        lpStartupInfo
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)  # _Out_       lpProcessInformation

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429
WIN(advapi32.CreateProcessAsUserW, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.HANDLE,        # _In_opt_    hToken
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpApplicationName
    wintypes.LPWSTR,        # _Inout_opt_ lpCommandLine
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # _In_opt_    lpProcessAttributes
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # _In_opt_    lpThreadAttributes
    wintypes.BOOL,          # _In_        bInheritHandles
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwCreationFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpEnvironment
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpCurrentDirectory
    LPSTARTUPINFO,          # _In_        lpStartupInfo
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)  # _Out_       lpProcessInformation

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682434
WIN(advapi32.CreateProcessWithTokenW, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.HANDLE,        # _In_        hToken
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwLogonFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpApplicationName
    wintypes.LPWSTR,        # _Inout_opt_ lpCommandLine
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwCreationFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpEnvironment
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpCurrentDirectory
    LPSTARTUPINFO,          # _In_        lpStartupInfo
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)  # _Out_       lpProcessInformation

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431
WIN(advapi32.CreateProcessWithLogonW, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_        lpUsername
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpDomain
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_        lpPassword
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwLogonFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpApplicationName
    wintypes.LPWSTR,        # _Inout_opt_ lpCommandLine
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwCreationFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpEnvironment
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpCurrentDirectory
    LPSTARTUPINFO,          # _In_        lpStartupInfo
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)  # _Out_       lpProcessInformation


CREATION_TYPE_NORMAL = 0
CREATION_TYPE_LOGON  = 1
CREATION_TYPE_TOKEN  = 2
CREATION_TYPE_USER   = 3


class CREATIONINFO(object):
    __slots__ = ( 'dwCreationType',
                  'lpApplicationName', 'lpCommandLine', 'bUseShell',
                  'lpProcessAttributes', 'lpThreadAttributes', 'bInheritHandles',
                  'dwCreationFlags', 'lpEnvironment', 'lpCurrentDirectory',
                  'hToken', 'lpUsername', 'lpDomain', 'lpPassword', 'dwLogonFlags' )

    def __init__(self, dwCreationType = CREATION_TYPE_NORMAL, lpApplicationName = None, lpCommandLine = None, bUseShell = False,
                 lpProcessAttributes = None, lpThreadAttributes = None, bInheritHandles = False, dwCreationFlags = 0,
                 lpEnvironment = None, lpCurrentDirectory = None, hToken = None, dwLogonFlags = 0, lpUsername = None,
                 lpDomain = None, lpPassword = None):
        self.dwCreationType = dwCreationType
        self.lpApplicationName = lpApplicationName
        self.lpCommandLine = lpCommandLine
        self.bUseShell = bUseShell
        self.lpProcessAttributes = lpProcessAttributes
        self.lpThreadAttributes = lpThreadAttributes
        self.bInheritHandles = bInheritHandles
        self.dwCreationFlags = dwCreationFlags
        self.lpEnvironment = lpEnvironment
        self.lpCurrentDirectory = lpCurrentDirectory
        self.hToken = hToken
        self.lpUsername = lpUsername
        self.lpDomain = lpDomain
        self.lpPassword = lpPassword
        self.dwLogonFlags = dwLogonFlags


def create_environment(environ):
    if environ is None:
        return None
    items = ['%s=%s' % (k, environ[k]) for k in sorted(environ)]
    buf = '\x00'.join(items)
    length = len(buf) + 2 if buf else 1
    return ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(buf, length)


def create_process(commandline = None, creationinfo = None, startupinfo = None):
    if creationinfo is None:
        creationinfo = CREATIONINFO()
    if startupinfo is None:
        startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
    elif isinstance(startupinfo, subprocess.STARTUPINFO):
        startupinfo = STARTUPINFO(dwFlags = startupinfo.dwFlags,
                                  hStdInput = startupinfo.hStdInput,
                                  hStdOutput = startupinfo.hStdOutput,
                                  hStdError = startupinfo.hStdError,
                                  wShowWindow = startupinfo.wShowWindow)
    si, ci, pi = startupinfo, creationinfo, PROCESS_INFORMATION()
    if commandline is None:
        commandline = ci.lpCommandLine
    if not commandline is None:
        if ci.bUseShell:
            si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
            si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
            comspec = os.environ.get("ComSpec", os.path.join(os.environ["SystemRoot"], "System32", "cmd.exe"))
            commandline = '"{}" /c "{}"'.format(comspec, commandline)
        commandline = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(commandline)
    dwCreationFlags = ci.dwCreationFlags | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT
    lpEnvironment = create_environment(ci.lpEnvironment)
    if ((dwCreationFlags & DETACHED_PROCESS)
            and ((dwCreationFlags & CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
                 or (ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_LOGON) or (ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_TOKEN))):
        raise RuntimeError('DETACHED_PROCESS is incompatible with CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, which is implied for the logon and token creation types')
    if ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_NORMAL:
        if not kernel32.CreateProcessW(ci.lpApplicationName, commandline, ci.lpProcessAttributes, ci.lpThreadAttributes, ci.bInheritHandles,
                                       dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, ci.lpCurrentDirectory, ctypes.byref(si), ctypes.byref(pi)):
            raise RuntimeError("CreateProcessW failed with error code %d!" % win32api.GetLastError())
    elif ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_LOGON:
        if not advapi32.CreateProcessWithLogonW(ci.lpUsername, ci.lpDomain, ci.lpPassword, ci.dwLogonFlags, ci.lpApplicationName, commandline,
                                                dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, ci.lpCurrentDirectory, ctypes.byref(si), ctypes.byref(pi)):
            raise RuntimeError("CreateProcessWithLogonW failed with error code %d!" % win32api.GetLastError())
    elif ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_TOKEN:
        if not advapi32.CreateProcessWithTokenW(ci.hToken, ci.dwLogonFlags, ci.lpApplicationName, commandline, dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment,
                                                ci.lpCurrentDirectory, ctypes.byref(si), ctypes.byref(pi)):
            raise RuntimeError("CreateProcessWithTokenW failed with error code %d!" % win32api.GetLastError())
    elif ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_USER:
        if not advapi32.CreateProcessAsUserW(ci.hToken, ci.lpApplicationName, commandline, ci.lpProcessAttributes, ci.lpThreadAttributes,
                                             ci.bInheritHandles, dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, ci.lpCurrentDirectory, ctypes.byref(si),
                                             ctypes.byref(pi)):
            raise RuntimeError("CreateProcessAsUserW failed with error code %d!" % win32api.GetLastError())
    else:
        raise ValueError('invalid process creation type')
    return pi


def LogonUser(domain, user, password, bNetwork = False):
    return win32security.LogonUser(user, domain, password,
                                   win32con.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK if bNetwork else win32con.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                                   win32con.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)


def AdjustPriv(priv, bEnable = True, prc = None):
    if prc is None:
        prc = win32api.GetCurrentProcess()
    htoken = win32security.OpenProcessToken(prc, win32security.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | win32security.TOKEN_QUERY)
    id = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, priv)
    if bEnable:
        newPriv = [ ( id, win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED ) ]
    else:
        newPriv = [ ( id, 0 ) ]
    win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, 0, newPriv)
    rc = win32api.GetLastError()
    if rc:
        print("AdjustPriv of %s failed with error code %d!" % (priv, rc))


class Popen(subprocess.Popen):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        ci = self._creationinfo = kwds.pop('creationinfo', CREATIONINFO())
        if kwds.pop('suspended', False):
            ci.dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_SUSPENDED
        self._child_started = False
        super(Popen, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)

    if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
        def _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
                           cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo,
                           creationflags, shell, to_close, p2cread, p2cwrite,
                           c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite):
            """Execute program (MS Windows version)"""
            commandline = (args if isinstance(args, types.StringTypes) else
                           subprocess.list2cmdline(args))
            self._common_execute_child(executable, commandline, shell,
                                       close_fds, creationflags, env, cwd,
                                       startupinfo, p2cread, c2pwrite, errwrite, to_close)
    else:
        def _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
                           pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags,
                           shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread,
                           errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session):
            """Execute program (MS Windows version)"""
            assert not pass_fds, "pass_fds not supported on Windows."
            commandline = (args if isinstance(args, str) else
                           subprocess.list2cmdline(args))
            self._common_execute_child(executable, commandline, shell,
                                       close_fds, creationflags, env, cwd,
                                       startupinfo, p2cread, c2pwrite, errwrite)

    def _common_execute_child(self, executable, commandline, shell,
                              close_fds, creationflags, env, cwd,
                              startupinfo, p2cread, c2pwrite, errwrite,
                              to_close=()):
        ci = self._creationinfo
        if not executable is None:
            ci.lpApplicationName = executable
        if commandline:
            ci.lpCommandLine = commandline
        if shell:
            ci.bUseShell = shell
        if not close_fds:
            ci.bInheritHandles = int(not close_fds)
        if creationflags:
            ci.dwCreationFlags |= creationflags
        if not env is None:
            ci.lpEnvironment = env
        if not cwd is None:
            ci.lpCurrentDirectory = cwd
        if startupinfo is None:
            startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
        si = self._startupinfo = startupinfo
        default = None if sys.version_info[0] == 2 else -1
        if default not in ( p2cread, c2pwrite, errwrite ):
            si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
            si.hStdInput  = int(p2cread)
            si.hStdOutput = int(c2pwrite)
            si.hStdError  = int(errwrite)
        try:
            pi = create_process(creationinfo = ci, startupinfo = si)
        finally:
            if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
                if not p2cread is None:
                    p2cread.Close()
                    to_close.remove(p2cread)
                if not c2pwrite is None:
                    c2pwrite.Close()
                    to_close.remove(c2pwrite)
                if not errwrite is None:
                    errwrite.Close()
                    to_close.remove(errwrite)
            else:
                if p2cread != -1:
                    p2cread.Close()
                if c2pwrite != -1:
                    c2pwrite.Close()
                if errwrite != -1:
                    errwrite.Close()
                if hasattr(self, '_devnull'):
                    os.close(self._devnull)
        if not ci.dwCreationFlags & CREATE_SUSPENDED:
            self._child_started = True
        # Retain the process handle, but close the thread handle if it's no longer needed.
        self._processinfo = pi
        self._handle = pi.hProcess.Detach()
        self.pid = pi.dwProcessId
        if self._child_started:
            pi.hThread.Close()
        self.returncode = ctypes.WinError().winerror

    def start(self):
        if self._child_started:
            raise RuntimeError("processes can only be started once")
        hThread = self._processinfo.hThread
        prev_count = kernel32.ResumeThread(hThread)
        if prev_count > 1:
            for _ in range(1, prev_count):
                if kernel32.ResumeThread(hThread) <= 1:
                    break
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('cannot start the main thread')
        # The thread's previous suspend count was 0 or 1, so it should be running now.
        self._child_started = True
        hThread.Close()

    def __del__(self):
        if not self._child_started:
            try:
                if hasattr(self, '_processinfo'):
                    self._processinfo.hThread.Close()
            finally:
                if hasattr(self, '_handle'):
                    self.terminate()
        super(Popen, self).__del__()


def KillProcessTree(pid):
    try:
        import psutil
        parent = psutil.Process(pid)
        for child in parent.children(recursive = True):
            child.kill()
        parent.kill()
    except:
        pass


def RunAs(cmdLine, domain, user, password, bNetwork = False, cwd = None, bUseShell = False, bShow = True, hWaitStop = None, timeout = 0):
    if cwd is None:
        cwd = "C:\\Temp"
    token = LogonUser(domain, user, password, bNetwork)
    if not token:
        raise RuntimeError("LogonUser failed with error code %d!" % win32api.GetLastError())
    hToken = token.handle
    if bShow:
        ci = CREATIONINFO(CREATION_TYPE_USER, hToken = hToken, bUseShell = bUseShell)
        si = None
    else:
        ci = CREATIONINFO(CREATION_TYPE_USER, hToken = hToken, dwCreationFlags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW, bUseShell = bUseShell)
        si = STARTUPINFO(wShowWindow = SW_HIDE, dwFlags = CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW)
    AdjustPriv(win32security.SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME)
    AdjustPriv(win32security.SE_TCB_NAME)
    AdjustPriv(win32security.SE_CHANGE_NOTIFY_NAME)
    AdjustPriv(win32security.SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME)
    AdjustPriv(win32security.SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME)
    AdjustPriv(win32security.SE_CREATE_TOKEN_NAME)
    win32security.ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken)
    prc = Popen(cmdLine, creationinfo = ci, startupinfo = si, cwd = cwd, universal_newlines = True,
                stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
    hPrc = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, False, prc.pid)
    if timeout > 0:
        timeout *= 1000
    else:
        timeout = win32event.INFINITE
    if hWaitStop is None:
        rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(hPrc, int(timeout))
    else:
        rc = win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects(( hPrc, hWaitStop ), 0, int(timeout))
    win32security.RevertToSelf()
    if rc != WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        KillProcessTree(prc.pid)
        return -1, "", "Timeout running command."
    if rc == WAIT_OBJECT_1:
        KillProcessTree(prc.pid)
        return -2, "", "Command was cancelled."
    return prc.returncode, prc.stdout.read(), prc.stderr.read()

cmdLine = r"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C timeout /T 5 > nul"
rc, stdOut, stdErr = RunAs(cmdLine, "DOMAIN", "USER", pw, timeout = 0, bNetwork = True)
```

But it doesn't work. The process is created with the desired user, but when it is started it is immediately destroyed. Return code is 0. No output on stdout and no stderr. GetLastError also returns 0. No entry is shown in the event viewer.

Comment: Are you creating your service with Python or with C++? With Python I'd suggest to look at "runas" utility. With C++ - CreateProcessAsUser.

Comment: First, you should investigate [Managed Service Accounts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831451(v=ws.11).aspx), which may eliminate the need to do this at all by allowing you to run the service as a domain user.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, `CreateProcessWithLogonW` and `CreateProcessWithTokenW` default the desktop info in the process parameters to the caller's, e.g. "Service-0x0-3e7$\Default". OTOH, `CreateProcessAsUser` can be made to work without updating security descriptors. It defaults to leaving the desktop info blank. Following the [window-station connection rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684859), if the child process doesn't inherit the parent's WindowStation, the system creates a new one named for the logon session ID. So we need to control inheritance via `STARTUPINFOEX`.

Comment: @eryksun, CreateProcessAsUser might not be an option in this case because the service doesn't have admin privilege.  On the other hand, according to the documentation, CreateProcessWithTokenW only requires impersonation privilege (which services have by default) and does the permissions changes for you.  So it certainly shouldn't be necessary to do them yourself.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, the Secondary Logon service (i.e. `CreateProcessWithTokenW`) doesn't modify the security of the parent's WindowStation. It gets the logon-ID group (i.e. `SE_GROUP_LOGON_ID`) from the client's token, which it adds to the child's token. When the service runs as SYSTEM, it doesn't even have this group, so the create fails. When run as NETWORK SERVICE it has it, but it's for another logon ID instead of the hard-coded 0x3e4 ID. Anyway, it forces us to use the "Service-0x0-3e4$" WindowStation, which only has ACEs for NETWORK SERVICE and Administrators, so connecting fails.

Comment: I've tried **many** different implementations. But nothing works. Please can someone post a working example? It does not matter if it is in C++, because I can easily convert it into Python code.
The process to call is just a console application which should be run as a hidden process.
BTW: 1) runas cannot be used because I cannot provide the password with the call. 2) I cannot run the service as domain user because of password restrictions in the company, which forces the password to be changed each 6 months.

Comment: @MartinBammer, can you run the service as SYSYTEM to be able to call `CreateProcessAsUser`?

Comment: @eryksun: No, the service must not have such high privileges. The updater  can be run as a normal user because the files to be updated are writeable by the user. Thus a solution with CreateProcessWithTokenW,as you mentioned, is preferred.

Comment: Since you can't use `CreateProcessAsUser`, I can write a few functions to update the DACL of the WindowStation and Desktop to grant the logon-session SID the required access. I'll use the current WindowStation and open the "default" Desktop, which is what `CreateProcessWithTokenW` uses. I'll also include a ctypes-based function that calls `LogonUserEx` to easily get the logon-session SID. I'd use `win32security.LogonUserEx`, but it has a bug that randomly crashes the interpreter.

Comment: Repeating my original comment: managed service accounts are *specifically designed* for this situation; the password on the account is changed regularly and automatically, so there shouldn't be any conflict with the password policy you describe.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I've found out how to do this. It is rather complicated and I had to merge the code from several examples (some of them in C). The below example works when executed as **Network Service** or **System** user. It doesn't matter if executed in user session or session 0.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import msvcrt
import win32security
import win32con
import win32pipe
import win32process
import win32api
import win32net
import win32file
import win32event
import win32profile
import win32service


GENERIC_ACCESS = win32con.GENERIC_READ | win32con.GENERIC_WRITE | win32con.GENERIC_EXECUTE | win32con.GENERIC_ALL

WINSTA_ALL = (win32con.WINSTA_ACCESSCLIPBOARD  | win32con.WINSTA_ACCESSGLOBALATOMS | \
win32con.WINSTA_CREATEDESKTOP    | win32con.WINSTA_ENUMDESKTOPS      | \
win32con.WINSTA_ENUMERATE        | win32con.WINSTA_EXITWINDOWS       | \
win32con.WINSTA_READATTRIBUTES   | win32con.WINSTA_READSCREEN        | \
win32con.WINSTA_WRITEATTRIBUTES  | win32con.DELETE                   | \
win32con.READ_CONTROL            | win32con.WRITE_DAC                | \
win32con.WRITE_OWNER)

DESKTOP_ALL = (win32con.DESKTOP_CREATEMENU      | win32con.DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW  | \
win32con.DESKTOP_ENUMERATE       | win32con.DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL   | \
win32con.DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK | win32con.DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD | \
win32con.DESKTOP_READOBJECTS     | win32con.DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP | \
win32con.DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS    | win32con.DELETE                | \
win32con.READ_CONTROL            | win32con.WRITE_DAC             | \
win32con.WRITE_OWNER)


def runAsDomainUser(domainName, userName, password, cmdLine, maxWait):
    # maxWait = Maximum execution time in ms
    userGroupSid = win32security.LookupAccountName(domainName, userName)[0]
    # Login as domain user and create new session
    userToken = win32security.LogonUser(userName, domainName, password,
                                        win32con.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                                        win32con.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
    rc = win32api.GetLastError()
    if userToken is None or (rc != 0):
        return -1, "", "LogonUser failed with RC=%d!" % rc
    profileDir = win32profile.GetUserProfileDirectory(userToken)
    tokenUser = win32security.GetTokenInformation(userToken, win32security.TokenUser)

    # Set access rights to window station
    hWinSta = win32service.OpenWindowStation("winsta0", False, win32con.READ_CONTROL | win32con.WRITE_DAC )
    # Get security descriptor by winsta0-handle
    secDescWinSta = win32security.GetUserObjectSecurity(hWinSta, win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION
                                                                 | win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION
                                                                 | win32con.GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
    # Get DACL from security descriptor
    daclWinSta = secDescWinSta.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
    if daclWinSta is None:
        # Create DACL if not exisiting
        daclWinSta = win32security.ACL()
    # Add ACEs to DACL for specific user group
    daclWinSta.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION_DS, GENERIC_ACCESS, userGroupSid)
    daclWinSta.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION_DS, WINSTA_ALL, userGroupSid)
    # Set modified DACL for winsta0
    win32security.SetSecurityInfo(hWinSta, win32security.SE_WINDOW_OBJECT, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                                  None, None, daclWinSta, None)

    # Set access rights to desktop
    hDesktop = win32service.OpenDesktop("default", 0, False, win32con.READ_CONTROL
                                                             | win32con.WRITE_DAC
                                                             | win32con.DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS
                                                             | win32con.DESKTOP_READOBJECTS)
    # Get security descriptor by desktop-handle
    secDescDesktop = win32security.GetUserObjectSecurity(hDesktop, win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION
                                                                   | win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION
                                                                   | win32con.GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION )
    # Get DACL from security descriptor
    daclDesktop = secDescDesktop.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
    if daclDesktop is None:
        #create DACL if not exisiting
        daclDesktop = win32security.ACL()
    # Add ACEs to DACL for specific user group
    daclDesktop.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION_DS, GENERIC_ACCESS, userGroupSid)
    daclDesktop.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION_DS, DESKTOP_ALL, userGroupSid)
    # Set modified DACL for desktop
    win32security.SetSecurityInfo(hDesktop, win32security.SE_WINDOW_OBJECT, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                                  None, None, daclDesktop, None)

    # Setup stdin, stdOut and stderr
    secAttrs = win32security.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES()
    secAttrs.bInheritHandle = 1
    stdOutRd, stdOutWr = win32pipe.CreatePipe(secAttrs, 0)
    stdErrRd, stdErrWr = win32pipe.CreatePipe(secAttrs, 0)

    ppid = win32api.GetCurrentProcess()
    tmp = win32api.DuplicateHandle(ppid, stdOutRd, ppid, 0, 0, win32con.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
    win32file.CloseHandle(stdOutRd)
    stdOutRd = tmp

    environment = win32profile.CreateEnvironmentBlock(userToken, False)

    startupInfo = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
    startupInfo.dwFlags = win32con.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
    startupInfo.hStdOutput = stdOutWr
    startupInfo.hStdError = stdErrWr

    hPrc = win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(
                            userToken,
                            None,               # appName
                            cmdLine,            # commandLine
                            None,               # processAttributes
                            None,               # threadAttributes
                            1,                  # bInheritHandles
                            win32process.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, # dwCreationFlags
                            environment,        # newEnvironment
                            profileDir,         # currentDirectory
                            startupInfo)[0]

    win32file.CloseHandle(stdErrWr)
    win32file.CloseHandle(stdOutWr)
    win32security.RevertToSelf()

    # Wait for process to complete
    stdOutBuf = os.fdopen(msvcrt.open_osfhandle(stdOutRd, 0), "rb")
    stdErrBuf = os.fdopen(msvcrt.open_osfhandle(stdErrRd, 0), "rb")
    win32event.WaitForSingleObject(hPrc, maxWait)
    stdOut = stdOutBuf.read()
    stdErr = stdErrBuf.read()
    rc = win32process.GetExitCodeProcess(hPrc)
    return rc, str(stdOut, "utf-8"), str(stdErr, "utf-8")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmdLine = "C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe"
    domainName = input("Domain: ")
    userName = input("User: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    print(runAsDomainUser(domainName, userName, password, cmdLine, 60000))
```